# Requests are timing-out when light payload is applied to .Net Core Web Api

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, amazon-ecs

I have an API which basically receives a request and pushes it to an SQS queue, nothing complicated.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Post([FromBody]object message, [FromHeader] string source)
    {
        if (message== null)
            return new UnsupportedMediaTypeResult();
        if (PublishMessageToSQS(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(message),source))
            return StatusCode(201);
        return StatusCode(500);
    }
    private bool PublishMessage(string message, string source)
    {
        try
        {
            RetryWhenException.Do(
                () =>
                {
                    SendMessageRequest request = new SendMessageRequest()
                    {
                        MessageBody = message,
                        MessageAttributes = new Dictionary<string, MessageAttributeValue>(),
                        QueueUrl = "my queue",
                    };
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(source))
                        request.MessageAttributes.Add("source", new MessageAttributeValue()
                        {
                            StringValue = source,
                            DataType = "String"
                        });
                    var result = sqsClient.SendMessageAsync(request).Result;
                }, 3, 1000);
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //log
            throw;
        }
    }
```

This API is containerized and deployed to AWS ECS on low resources machine (0.25 VCpu, 512 MB RAM).

When applying a light load on the API (10 requests per second), requests start to timeout after a while.

I stopped receiving timeouts when applying one of:

1- Use more resources (2 VCPU, 4GB RAM)

2-  make my action async.

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> Post([FromBody]object message, [FromHeader] string source)
    {
        if (message== null)
            return new UnsupportedMediaTypeResult();
        if (await PublishMessageToSQS(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(message), source))
            return StatusCode(201);
        return StatusCode(500);
    }

private async Task<bool> PublishMessage(string message, string source)
    {
        try
        {
            await RetryWhenException.Do(
             async () =>
              {
                  SendMessageRequest request = new SendMessageRequest()
                  {
                      MessageBody = message,
                      MessageAttributes = new Dictionary<string, MessageAttributeValue>(),
                      QueueUrl = "my queue",
                  };
                  if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(source))
                      request.MessageAttributes.Add("source", new MessageAttributeValue()
                      {
                          StringValue = source,
                          DataType = "String"
                      });
                  var result = await sqsClient.SendMessageAsync(request);
              }, 3, 1000);
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
         //log
         throw;
        }
    }
```

RetryWhenException code:

```
public static class RetryWhenException
{
    public static void Do(Action action, int maxAttemptCount = 3, int retryInterval = 1000)
    {
        var exceptions = new List<Exception>();
        for (var attempted = 0; attempted < maxAttemptCount; attempted++)
        {
            try
            {
                if (attempted > 0)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(retryInterval);
                }
                action();
                return;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                exceptions.Add(ex);
            }
        }
        throw new AggregateException(exceptions);
    }
}
```

I know that Async frees threads, but pushing to SQS is not that costy and the number of requests is not that high.

I really don't understand why I was getting timeouts when applying such low payload, and why async did the trick, any explanation?

Comment: I could imagine that `PublishMessageToSQS` is blocking, and the async variant of it will free up the Thread and return back as soon as it is done. In order to verify that you would need to share the code of `PublishMessageToSQS` with us.

Comment: @Twenty question is updated, I know that the old version of code was blocking, but I imagine that .Net core already starts a new thread per request.

Comment: AFAIK ASP.NET Core does not start a new thread per request. Instead all requests are handled by a dedicated thread pool (whose thread count is controlled by `KestrelServerOptions.ThreadCount`, and defaults to half the number of processors), and there is no guarantee that each request is served by a single thread. Therefore any long-running synchronous I/O can starve the thread pool real quickly. More information [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/performance-best-practices#avoid-blocking-calls)